# Solvability of integral equation $f(x)=g(A(||g||)x)$

Tags: integration, analysis

I meet this problem in a  unpublished paper. Consider integral equation
$$
f(x)=g(A(||g||)x)
$$
where $f\in H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is a given function, $A:\mathbb R^+\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ is a continue function, and $||\cdot||$ is $L^2$-norm.  How to know whether there is a $g\in H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ meet the above equation ?

In fact, my question is harder, the integral equation is 
$$
f(x)=g(A(||\nabla g||)x).
$$
Since I want to deal the easy situation first, I ask the above equation. Besides, I think it is not solvability for all continue $A$. There should be some request for the $A$. But I don't know what is it.

Thanks for any hint or answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go for the harder question. Once $g$ is fixed, $A(\|\nabla g\|)$ is a constant. This suggests to look for $g(x)=f(x/a)$ for some $a>0$. From
$$
g(A(\|\nabla g\|)\,x)=g\Bigl(A(\|\nabla g\|\,\frac{x}{a}\Bigr)=f(x)
$$
we see that $a=A(\|\nabla g\|)$. IS this possible? We have
$$
\|\nabla g\|=a^{\tfrac{n-2}{2}}\,\|\nabla f\|=A(\|\nabla g\|)^{\tfrac{n-2}{2}}\,\|\nabla f\|.
$$
We impose now the condition that the equation $b=A(b)^{\tfrac{n-2}{2}}\,\|\nabla f\|$ has a solution $b>0$ and take $a=A(b)$.

Comment: But $g$ is not fixed, I can't understand you.

Comment: What I mean, is that $A(\nabla g\|)$ is a constant (depending on $g$, but independent of $x$). I reduce the problem to find $a>0$ such that $g(x)=f(x/a)$ solves the problem.